# How to obtain Magellan 6.5m telescope data?

Tags: raw-data

I research about Bullet cluster.

Because [Clowe et al. (2006)](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0608407) used Magellan's IMACS data, So I entered the [SAO Magellan data archive site](http://tdc-www.harvard.edu/computing/magellan/).

But I could not find the method to obtain the data.

Is there no method except for sending e-mail to SAO manager?

Is there no site like [MAST](https://mast.stsci.edu/portal/Mashup/Clients/Mast/Portal.html)?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but note that Magellan is a privately ownded telescope(s), so the data rights will be quite different to things like HST and Kepler.

Comment: I got it, thank you.

Comment: I found some method. But it is not about magellan 6.5m data archive. Originally, the data what I want is the data which is used some paper. So I search this paper in [NASA/ADS](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/). There are the data what I want in the paper page!